# Unity first game project - How do I change scene when reaching my goal area?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a small game using Unity for a school project. The purpose of the game is to control a ball, collect coins and reach the goal area. My goal area is made up of a capsule that I have flattened out and put a sphere collider on it. How do I get to shift scene/level when reaching the goal area? What code do I need to write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the Sphere Collider to "Is Trigger" and add an OnTriggerEnter method to a script that you have attached to the goal area game object. Make sure the scene name matches a level that you have defined in the build settings.

```
public String NextLevelName;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(NextLevelName, LoadSceneMode.Single);
}
```

Comment: can I for example use my playerController script or do I have to create a new script a la "gameManager"? I have 3 levels. What do I need to write to be able to shift to the next scene every time a reach the goal area on each level? I've already set the sphere colliders to "is trigger" and added all 3 scenes in the build settings.

Comment: This script should be on the goal object. I would create a new script called "GoalProgress" or something similar. I just made a script change so you reuse this script in multiple levels. You can assign the script to the goal object, then drag that down into your Project Explorer, which will create a "prefab". Then you can drag that prefab into other levels and set the "NextLevelName" variable in the Unity UI. Remember, Unity(and programming in general) is all about reuse!

Comment: Ok, I will try this out in a moment. I'll come back to you

Comment: No problem. Keep at it!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to add all scenes into the build settings. Then write

`SceneManager.LoadScene("Your Scene Name")`

in your script when you reach your goal area.

Comment: I've already added all the scenes into the build settings. I have a cameraController-script, a loadSceneOnClick-script for the game menu, a playerController script, a quitOnClick-script for the game menu, a selectOnInput-script for the game menu, a respawner-script for when the ball(player) falls of the course, and a rotator-script for coins and platforms. Do I have to make a new script for this issue?